# Eclipse build.properties Warning: The plug-in's classpath library '.' does not have a corresponding source build entry

Tags: eclipse

For the build.properties file in Eclipse I get the warning

```
The plug-in's classpath library '.' does not have a corresponding source build entry
```

The build.properties file has the following content:

```
bin.includes = .settings/,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               Processes/,\
               Resources/,\
               Schemas/,\
               Service Descriptors/,\
               .WebResources/,\
               pom.xml,\
               target/
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` entry in the bin.includes is the entry for the plugn's main source code. The build needs to know where to look for that source code. For a plugin using a `src` directory for the source you need

```
source.. = src/
```

in the build.properties to provide that information.

You might also need

```
output.. = bin/
```

to say where the output classes are located.

Comment: That fixed it. I added an (empty) source folder and added `source.. = src/` to build.properties